# A mistake - "!Package scrlayer Error: cannot define '\newpagestyle'

Tags: koma-script

Once I run my latex I receive the following mistake - !Package scrlayer Error: cannot define '\newpagestyle'.Can anyone please help me to resolve it? I use the following package associated with scrlayer (Before I was using scrpage2, but it became obsolete)

`\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}`

Below I include the code that can not be compiled:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2,authordate,giveninits=true, 
 backend=biber, natbib,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}


\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% package for including graphics with figure-environment
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{breqn}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{adjustbox}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
 \addbibresource{Reference.bib}
 \usepackage{bm}
 \usepackage{blindtext}
 \usepackage{multicol}
 \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{fancyvrb}
 \usepackage{subcaption}
 \usepackage{supertabular}
 \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
 \captionsetup{justification   = raggedright,
          singlelinecheck = false}

 \usepackage{makecell}
  \usepackage{tikz}
   
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}
 %\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
  \usepackage[left=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
  \pagestyle{myheadings}
  \usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

  \cfoot[]{\pagemark} 
  \setheadsepline[122mm]{0.3mm}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

  \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{> 
 {\centering\arraybackslash}p{\widthof{0.000}}}{#1}}    
  %
 \doublespacing
 \makeatletter
\def\@xfootnote[#1]{%
 \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{#1}%
 \@footnotemark\@footnotetext}
 \makeatother
 \begin{document}

\end{titlepage}









 \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please create a minimal document which results in this error? Which document class are you using? Does this happen without any other packages, or only if a certain other package is loaded?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added the code as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reduced your example to make it really minimal. Other packages are not material to the issue.

The culprit was `titlesec`. Removing it solves the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

 %\usepackage{titlesec}





\usepackage[left=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
  \pagestyle{myheadings}
  \usepackage[automark]
  {scrlayer-scrpage}

  \cfoot[]{\pagemark} 
  \setheadsepline[122mm]{0.3mm}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


 \begin{document}

asdfasdf


 \end{document}
```