# How to obtain a minitoc with classicthesis?

Tags: books, classicthesis, minitoc, etoc

Suppose you want to write a report with a local TOC at the beginning of each chapter. This can be obtained with the `minitoc` package. MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{minitoc}
%\input{classicthesis-config}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Apple}
\minitoc
\section{Alabama}
\section{Arizona}
\subsection{Afghanistan}
\subsection{Austria}

\chapter{Banana}

\chapter{Cherry}

\end{document}
```

The minitoc is visible here:

[image]

If one now wants to use the `classicthesis` template, the minitoc is no longer included in the produced PDF.

MWE: uncomment `input{classicthesis-config}`.

This seems to be a [known issue](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/issues/176/minitoc-package-does-not-work-with). I was wondering if there is any update to this. Or is there a workaround to obtain a minitoc?

Comment: Use titletoc? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79547/

Comment: @PhilipPirrip This gives the a `Package scrlayer Error: cannot define '\newpagestyle'` error. It can be solved by uncommenting `\usepackage[toctitles]{titlesec}` as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562110/a-mistake-package-scrlayer-error-cannot-define-newpagestyle), but then there seems to be a vertical spacing problem.

Comment: I do not know if the resulting vertical spacing problem of the obtained local TOC is due to settings of `titletoc` or of `classicthesis`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace `minitoc` with the package `etoc` with advantages (The first is that it is compatible with `classicthesis`, the second is that is well maintained).

The only changes are to replace `\minitoc` with `\localtableofcontents` and add the required  style (the last  separation rule).

I added  dummy text to get  meaningful tables of contents.

[image: a]

[image: c]

This is the code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\usepackage{etoc} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text <<<<

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\etocsettocstyle{\vskip0.3\baselineskip}{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\vskip0.5\baselineskip} % etoc style for local TOC

\chapter{Apple}
\localtableofcontents %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

1. \kant[1]
\section{Alabama}
2. \kant[2-4]
\section{Arizona}
3. \kant[5-7]
\subsection{Afghanistan}
4. \kant[8-9]
\subsection{Austria}
4. \kant[10-12]

\chapter{Banana}
\localtableofcontents %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

6. \kant[14]
\section{Split}
7. \kant[15]

\chapter{Cherry}
\localtableofcontents %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

7. \kant[18]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Furthermore, see the [etoc manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) for more information about the `\etocsettocstyle{}{}` command. You can use it to add a title before the toc, for instance.

Comment: Well, It seemed redundant to me. What else could that be? Why put more ink in such a nice minimalist style?

Comment: For instance, you can add a horizontal line before the `localtableofcontents` if you need to put text before it.